# What is best. Buying a one way ticket or a round ticket that is refundable

Tags: tickets, refunds, one-way

Im going to Australia for a year. I dont know exactly when im going back to my country (Chile), so i just want to buy a one way ticket but they cost the same as a round way ticket.
Could it be possible to buy a round ticket that is refundable and ask for the money of the return ticket?

Comment: Have you looked into the details of the conditions of the ticket that you would want to buy? I would expect them to only be refundable before you used the first flight of the ticket. There may also be the possibility to buy a round-trip ticket that is *changeable* for a fee with a return trip at the date of your best guess, and then change the return flight once you know when you want to return. There is also a thing called "open return" - they are less common today but you may want to ask your travel agent how much that would cost anyway.

Comment: You won't get a cheaper price by refunding the unused portion of the refundable return ticket, if that's what you mean.